# How to delete showing of table's grid in the QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

[image: http://i.imgur.com/O6PeOLy.png]

I mean to set `border: 0 px` of every cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [setShowGrid](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#showGrid-prop) or [setGridStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#gridStyle-prop) with Qt::NoPen on your QTableView/Widget. These properties can also be directly set in QtDesigner.